# Separate domain for a single language

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a website with three languages (Polish, English, and French) with English being the default. English and French should use a URL like domain.com/en and domain.com/fr; Polish should use a separate domain, domain.pl.

How can I achieve this?
I've seen suggestions to use `hook_language_negotiation_info()`, but it's not working for me at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is can be done using TMGMT, from the TMGMT domain setting you can set up configuration per domain. You can also check out this module => https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_site_settings